# How to tell the precedence of operators in a context free grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

How can we know which of the following logical operations ( or, and, not ) in the bellow context free grammar have higher precedence? Is there a general approach to this kind of problems?

X → X or Y | Y

Y → Y and Z | Z

Z → not Z | (X) | true | false

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an example approach:

```
expr -> addExpr;
addExpr -> multExpr (('+'|'-') multExpr)*;
multExpr -> terminalExpr (('*'|'/') terminalExpr)*;
terminalExpr -> integer | variable | '(' expr ')';
```

But the associativity is ambiguous. Here's a more explicit way in BNF:

```
expr -> addExpr;
addExpr -> addExpr '+' multExpr | addExpr '-' multExpr | multExpr;
multExpr -> multExpr '*' terminalExpr | multExpr '/' terminalExpr | terminalExpr;
terminalExpr -> integer | variable | '(' expr ')';
```

These grammars define the operators `*` and `/` as having more precedence as `+` and `-`. You declare the operation with higher precedence deeper in the parse tree, so they will be tried first by the parser.

Comment: good example. thanks. so what it means is that the operation with higher precedence should be lower in the parsing tree. maybe u can add that to your answer and id plus one it!

Comment: @rici huh I don't know what I was thinking :-\ Thanks for noticing this, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to add an exponential(**) operator to the above grammar(which is having the highest precedence) then I need to add this operation in the second last level of your grammar right?

Comment: @Prasanna Since exponentiation has a higher precedence than multiplication, you need to add a separate level to the grammar (between `multExpr` and `terminalExpr`) in order to handle it correctly.