# Operator precedence when converting from CFG to LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, operators

I'm working in translating a context free grammar into a LL(1) grammar. I'm trying to implement operator precedence. I'm dealing with this little code:

```
 'Expression ::= 'Expression ~ 'Op ~ 'Expression
      | 'Expression ~ LBRACKET() ~ 'Expression ~ RBRACKET()
      | 'Expression ~ DOT() ~ LENGTH()
      | 'Expression ~ DOT() ~ 'Identifier ~ LPAREN() ~ 'Args ~ RPAREN()
      | INTLITSENT | STRINGLITSENT
      | TRUE() | FALSE() | 'Identifier | THIS()
      | NEW() ~ INT() ~ LBRACKET() ~ 'Expression ~ RBRACKET()
      | NEW() ~ 'Identifier ~ LPAREN() ~ RPAREN()
      | BANG() ~ 'Expression
      | LPAREN() ~ 'Expression ~ RPAREN(),

 'Op ::= AND() | OR() | EQUALS() | LESSTHAN() | PLUS() | MINUS() | TIMES() | DIV(),
```

The important here is that I want to translate line

```
'Expression ::= 'Expression ~ 'Op ~ 'Expression
```

So that it actually implements precedence from high to low priority: !,*,/,+ -, < , ==, &&, ||. I found a good method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471876/how-to-tell-the-precedence-of-operators-in-a-context-free-grammar). But I'm worried that if I just write:

```
 'Expression ::= 'OrExpression
 'OrExpression ::= 'AndExpression ~ OR() ~ 'OrExpression | 'AndExpression,
 'AndExpression ::= 'EqualsExpression ~ AND() ~ 'AndExpression | 'EqualsExpression,
 'EqualsExpression ::= 'LessthanExpression ~ EQUALS() ~ 'EqualsExpression | 'LessthanExpression,
 'LessthanExpression ::= 'AddExpression ~ LESSTHAN() ~ 'LessthanExpression | 'AddExpression,
 'AddExpression ::= 'DivExpression ~ PLUS() ~ 'AddExpression | 'DivExpression ~ MINUS() ~ 'AddExpression | 'DivExpression,
 'DivExpression ::= 'TimesExpression ~ DIV() ~ 'DivExpression | 'TimesExpression,
 'TimesExpression ::= 'TimesExpression ~ TIMES() ~ 'TimesExpression | 'BangExpression,
 'BangExpression ::= BANG() ~ 'BangExpression | 'BracketExpression,
 'BracketExpression ::= 'Expression ~ LBRACKET() ~ 'Expression ~ RBRACKET() | 'DotExpression,
 'DotExpression ::= 'Expression ~ DOT() ~ LENGTH() | 'Expression ~ DOT() ~ 'Identifier ~ LPAREN() ~ 'Args ~ RPAREN() | 'NewExpression,
 'NewExpression ::= NEW() ~ INT() ~ LBRACKET() ~ 'Expression ~ RBRACKET() | NEW() ~ 'Identifier ~ LPAREN() ~ RPAREN() | 'BasicExpression
 'BasicExpression ::= INTLITSENT | STRINGLITSENT | TRUE() | FALSE() | 'Identifier | THIS() | LPAREN() ~ 'Expression ~ RPAREN()
```

then removing left recursion gets quite nasty. Can you think of others ways of doing it?

Comment: The link is not a "good method" since it won't work. But you are not following it either.

Comment: You write `OrEx -> OrEx OR OrEx` whereas the (incorrect) answer would have `OrEx -> AndEx OR AndEx`. The linked question has the correct grammar, `OrEx -> OrEx OR AndEx`, but it's not LL(1). Your proposed solution isn't LL(1) either; because it is completely ambiguous, it is also not LR(1).

Comment: @rici thank you for your comment. following your ideas i came up with the new grammar (i edited my post) although i actually reversed the order so rule OrEx -> OrEx OR AndEx would look like OrEx -> AndEx OR OrEx so that I have less left recursion. However left recursion is still there and in a very bad way 'DotExpression ::= 'Expression ~ DOT() ... i'm solving it but it gets really complicated

Comment: If you reverse the rule, you reverse the associativity, so 1-2-7 no longer means the same thing. Why do you insist on an LL(1) grammar?

Comment: @rici I'm building a compiler that uses some other software that requires the grammar to be LL(1) although I understand it isn't the best choice. in fact associativity is supposed to be to the right and afterwards there is a tool that translates my parse tree into a abstract tree which reverses associativity

Comment: @rici but the big problem  is in left recursion, if i use ullman's algorithm to solve it i get so many rules for 'BracketExpression or 'DotExpression